# Are signed hexdecimal literals possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, literals

I have an array of bitmasks, the idea being to use them to clear a specified number of the least significant bits of an integer that is being used as a set of flags. It is defined as follows:

```
int clearLow[10]=
{
0xffffffff, 0xfffffffe, 0xfffffffc, 0xfffffff8, 0xfffffff0, 0xffffffe0, 0xffffffc0, 0xffffff80, 0xffffff00, 0xfffffe00
};
```

I recently switching to using gcc 4.8 I have found that this array starts throwing warnings,

```
warning: narrowing conversion of ‘4294967295u’ from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘int’ inside { } is ill-formed in C++11
etc
etc
```

Clearly my hexadecimal literals are being taken as `unsigned int`s and the fix is easy as, honestly, I do not care if this array is `int` or `unsigned int` it just needs to have the appropriate bits set in each cell, but my question is this:

Are there any ways to set literals in hexadecimal, for the purposes of simply setting bits, without the compiler assuming them to be unsigned?

Comment: You can write them with a negative sign and an appropriate negative value. 0xffffffff can't fit into an `int` if it's 32 bits.

Comment: It fits in perfectly, 32 bits. That is all I am doing, specifying which bits need to set and which don't. Writing these as negative hexadecimal values defeats the purpose of writing them in hex in the first place, namely making clear what is set and what isn't.

Comment: It's a positive value that would overflow a 32-bit signed integer. If you want an array of signed ints, give the values you really want (or explicitly cast them), and if you want an array of unsigned ints, declare it as such.

Comment: What I really want is an array of 32 bit masks to be used with bitwise operations no numerical operations at all, but I get your point. If you write it up as a quick answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just want an array of `unsigned int` to use for your bit masking:

```
const unsigned clearLow[] = {
    0xffffffff, 0xfffffffe, 0xfffffffc, 0xfffffff8, 0xfffffff0, 0xffffffe0, 0xffffffc0, 0xffffff80, 0xffffff00, 0xfffffe00
};
```

Comment: I get the idea of using unsigned ints for bit masking, and I will from now on, but check what you entered for your answer. That does not yield what I have at all. ~(1<<1) is 0xFFFFFFFD not 0xFFFFFFFC as it should be. I do not one bit unset, I want all bits below the bit index specified by the index in the array unset.

Comment: @JamesMatta, Oh, shoot, sorry about that.

Comment: No, worries, though I will say that I defined it with the hexidecimal values like that because I could not see a compact notation that would make the appropriate values. Now that your answer is modified, I shall accept it as promised.

Answer (score 4):

You describe that you just want to use the values as operands to bit operations. As that is the case, just always **use unsigned datatypes**. That's the simple solution.